# Actionscript Plotter Communication

Tags: actionscript-3, air

We are having an application where we want to use Adobe AIR application to communicate with Plotter hardware which is currently used for cutting the clothing material according to given inputs.Currently the software used for same is called Lectra which is the SW from plotter company.This SW is also used for designing purpose.

Now we want to create our own SW with our needs and want to know how we can communicate with Plotter to cut the material using our software.

Does anybody has used Actionscript with plotter like cutters/printers? Is there any other utility which can be used through air app and communicated with plotter?

Any pointers in right directions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Enviroment

you can use **c/c++** or **visual c++** and make one executable file which have all functionality like communication with you hardware, giving input to it, taking response from it ETC. after making this .exe file you can directly communicate with this .exe file using socket connection.

detail description of socket communication with air giving in its [Documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/creating_socket_server.html) and [other tutorial are also available](http://blog.aboutme.be/2011/06/07/handling-websocket-connections-with-adobe-air-serversocket/)

may this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for the response. But as the hardware is from third party and we dont control over it, so how can I write code for it?